# Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to import tensorflow but every time i do `import tensorflow` i get this annoying error it says
"Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime." i have looked my error into
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors but i did not find my answer yet i probably missed it But....

My error:

```
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I used `pip install tensorflow` also if i do `pip install tensorflow` in my console i get "Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (2.3.1)"
but when i do `import tensorflow` i get my `Import Error`

also my pip version is 20.2.4

Comment: _And my pip version is 20.2.4_ Did you install the package with pip, or Conda? Also, are you using the base/root Conda environment?

Comment: @AMC I used pip not conda

Comment: This issue might be because You have not installed the `Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable` package or your CPU does not support `AVX instructions`.                
                                                                                                                            
 Please take a look at [system requirements](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#system-requirements) and check if you have correct dependencies installed. Thanks

Comment: @PyCoder64 _I used pip not conda_ In a Conda environment, right? If so, why not use Conda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using Anaconda it will support

## Tensorflow == 2.1.0

create a new environment for tensorflow

```
conda create -n tf tensorflow
activate tf
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured how to do it for me i just needed to do:
`pip install tensorflow==1.15`