# ImportError with tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Parth Manghnani\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in 
from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: The specified module could not be found.

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

Comment: Please, check [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and it is possible duplicate of [error: Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64733430/failed-to-load-the-native-tensorflow-runtime).

Comment: On windows you need to have [Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019 Redistributable (x64)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads-2647da03-1eea-4433-9aff-95f26a218cc0). For more details you can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65993414/14290681). Thanks!